# EEA family permit refused

Tags: united-kingdom

I applied for an EEA family permit on the basis that my brother is Swedish national. I have got the refusal although its stated that if EEA national is planning to move to UK within six months of date of application he can apply for his extended family member. They also didn't accept the birth certificate which I had provided. I am attaching a copy of decision. Should i appeal this decision?

> You state that your brother is a Swedish national. You have provided
> evidence  that your sponsor holds a Swedish passport.
>
> Only those family members referred to under Article 2 of the Directive
> 2004/38/EC have an automatic right to join or accompany an EEA family
> member  to another member state when that EEA national is exercising a
> Treaty right.  Article 3 of Directive 2004/38/EC provides the basis
> for a member state to  consider other relatives, such as ‘extended
> family members’ and determine the  terms of entry and residence to
> such ‘beneficiaries’ in accordance with their own  domestic
> legislation. (Article 3(2)).  The United Kingdom has transposed the
> terms of Article 3 into Regulation 8 of  the Immigration (European
> Economic Area) Regulations 2016. As Regulation  8(4) makes clear, the
> United Kingdom is allowed to set terms on when it will  accept
> extended family members and allow them to reside in the United Kingdom
> as family members of an EEA national.   To apply for an EEA permit as
> the extended family member of an EEA national in  accordance with
> regulation 8 of the Immigration (European Economic Area)  regulations
> 2016, you must satisfy that you are financially dependent on your
> sponsor.  Guidance states that financial dependence should be
> interpreted as meaning that  the family member needs the financial
> support of the EEA national or his or her  spouse/civil partner in
> order to meet the family members essential needs in the  country where
> they are present – not in order to have a certain level of income.
> The applicant must also provide evidence to show their EEA national
> sponsor  has enough money to support them and the applicant is reliant
> on them for this.  I note that on your application you state that you
> are financially supported by your  sponsor. As evidence of this you
> have provided money transfer remittance  receipts. However, I am not
> satisfied that this sufficiently demonstrates that you  are dependent
> on your sponsor to meet your essential needs. Unfortunately, this
> limited amount of evidence in isolation does not prove that you are
> financially  dependent on your sponsor. I would expect to see
> substantial evidence of this  over a prolonged period.  Furthermore,
> the fact of transferring money is not evidence that it is needed by
> the recipient. You have not provided any evidence regarding your own
> financial  situation such as bank statements or other documents
> indicating financial ingoing  and outgoings. You have provided no
> evidence to demonstrate yours and your  family’s circumstances
> including your income, expenditure and evidence of your  financial
> position which would prove that without the financial support of your
> sponsor your essential living needs could not be met.   As evidence
> of your relationship with your sponsor you have provided yours and
> your sponsors birth certificate that was registered on 26th September
> 2020  confirming that your date of births are 1996 and 1991,  these
> registrations took place 24 and 29 years after your births. Due to the
> length  of time between birth event and registration this certificate
> cannot be accepted as reliable evidence in the absence of other
> relevant birth documentation issued at  the time of the event or other
> credible documentation evidencing your parentage.   Every application
> received by this office is assessed on its own merits using the
> evidence that has been supplied with the application and all other
> evidence  available to me. However, the submission of repeat
> applications within a short  space of time is unlikely, without
> significant, detailed additional evidence, to  satisfy the Entry
> Clearance Officer and alter the decisions that have previously  been
> made. I therefore refuse your EEA Family Permit application because I
> am not satisfied that  you meet all of the requirements of regulation
> 12 (see ECGs EUN2.23) of the  Immigration (European Economic Area)
> Regulations 2016.

Comment: Are you financial depended on your brother? Just being adult siblings is not enough to get the family permit.

Comment: @Fahim Appeal on what basis? We can’t answer unless you explain your personal circumstances further - are you financially dependent on your brother? Why were your births only registered recently? If you can’t address the refusal reasons, an appeal or another application is pointless

Comment: @Traveller As far as I'm aware EEA family permits aren't being issued anymore, as of one month ago today, because the transition period for the UK's withdrawal from the EU has ended, so a new application would be pointless in any event.  If the brother has settled status then Fahim should consider whether an EUSS family permit application might be fruitful.